# How to change selection behaviour of Bootstrap's typeahead

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

When using the typeahead functionality from Twitter Bootstrap ([example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)) the first suggestion gets selected when I press TAB and when I press ENTER. However, when a user does NOT want to use one of the suggestions there is only one way to achieve this and that is grabbing the mouse and clicking on the submit button.

I want a way of doing this with only the keyboard, TAB or ARROW-UP both seem intuitive, but in both cases I can't get the default behaviour of Bootstrap to stop. I tried both preventDefault() and stopPropagation().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I solved this was by initializing the list with suggestions with the current query. So when pressing enter or tab the query is selected. When pressing arrow-down or arrow-up + enter a real suggestion is selected.

This is similar to what Chrome does when typing something in the url bar.

Comment: Note that ESC does stop the autocomplete behaviour and lets you enter  you own query.

Comment: that means we should press enter twice ?

Comment: i know this is an old post, but would like to see this implementation too

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but still relevant. You can remove this with the following. Find the following in the typeahead.jquery.js file and comment it out

```
items.first().addClass('active')
```